# Improper Riemann integral questions

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

The function $f:(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}$ $\left(\text{so on $(0,\infty)$ we have $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$}\right)$.
1. Determine whether $f$ is improperly Riemann integrable over $[0,1]$, and calculate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \; dx$ if it is.
The improper Riemann integral is the limit
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} &:= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \int_{\epsilon}^{1} \frac{dx}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}} \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \left[\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{2}+1}}{-\frac{1}{2}+1}\right]_{\epsilon}^{1} \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to0^+} 2-\left(2\sqrt{\epsilon}\right) \\
&= 2
\end{split}
\end{equation*} 
2. Determine whether $f$ is improperly Riemann integrable over $[1,\infty)$, and calculate $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \; dx$ if it is.
The improper Riemann integral is the limit
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} &:= \lim_{\epsilon\to\infty} \int_{1}^{\epsilon} \frac{dx}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}} \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to\infty} \left[\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{2}+1}}{-\frac{1}{2}+1}\right]_{1}^{\epsilon} \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to\infty} \left(2\sqrt{\epsilon}\right)-2 \\
&= \infty.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Hence, $f$ is not improperly Riemann integrable over $[1,\infty)$.
3. Explain why $f$ is not improperly Riemann integrable over $[0,\infty)$.
4. Is $f$ improperly Riemann integrable over $[-1,1]$? Briefly explain your answer.
Well we get $2-2i$.
Any help for the third and fourth questions will be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

3. By additivity of the integral:
   $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\;dx = \int_0^1 f(x)\;dx + \int_1^\infty f(x)\;dx$$
4. Note that $f$ is symmetric: $f(-x)=f(x)$. How can you then rewrite the integral?

Comment: 4. Oh of course then we get $2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \; dx=4$?.

Comment: @squenshl Yes, that‘s right.